# how to assign the textbox to particular column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        TextBox txt= e.Control as TextBox;

        if (dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.Equals("Header"))
        {
            if (txt!= null)
            {
                txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ..datasource...;
                txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I get start edit at 1st column, it's working fine. I have more then one datagridtextbox column so auto completion working at all columns. I want to prevent that and have to bind in `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1`.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Are you trying to set the AutoComplete mode for all the DataGridTextBox columns, or only the first column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this

```
 var text = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText;
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Text = text;
```